# Volley NoConnectionError java.io.IOException on continious switching between activities

Tags: java, android, android-volley, okhttp

I have two Fragment activities namely Feed and Profile.Both of these activities request some data from the server using a volley JSON request.I have also created a singleton class that encapsulates the Volley RequestQueue. Initially, both the activities load data properly using volley. However, after continuous switching between the activities Volley throws the following error and afterward no requests are sent to the server for some period.

```
1-12 14:48:58.146 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{www.grabuk.com:80, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=43.255.154.57 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
11-12 14:48:58.146 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:151)
11-12 14:48:58.146 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
11-12 14:48:58.146 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{www.grabuk.com:80, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=43.255.154.57 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
11-12 14:48:58.151 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:258)
11-12 14:48:58.151 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:104)
11-12 14:48:58.151 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:1154)
11-12 14:48:58.151 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:982)
11-12 14:48:58.151 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:474)
11-12 14:48:58.151 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:410)
11-12 14:48:58.151 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:532)
11-12 14:48:58.151 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:110)
11-12 14:48:58.151 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
11-12 14:48:58.151 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:    ... 1 more
11-12 14:48:58.151 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=...
11-12 14:48:58.151 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:210)
11-12 14:48:58.151 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:239)
11-12 14:48:58.151 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:    ... 9 more
11-12 14:48:58.156 27190-27190/com.tdn E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn D/error:: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{www.grabuk.com:80, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=43.255.154.57 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{www.grabuk.com:80, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=43.255.154.57 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:151)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{www.grabuk.com:80, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=43.255.154.57 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:258)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:104)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:1154)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:982)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:474)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:410)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:532)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:110)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:    ... 1 more
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=...
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:210)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:239)
11-12 14:48:58.181 27190-27190/com.tdn W/System.err:    ... 9 more
```

After waiting some time when I again switch between the activities the volley loads the data properly. I read a lot of questions on StackOverflow  but none of them seems to have solved my problem. This is what my volley request looks like:

```
    {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put(UID, String.valueOf(Singelton.getUserID()));
        params.put(COUNT,Integer.toString(cnt));

        RequestQueue requestQueue = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
        CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {

                Log.d("respnse:",response.toString());
                processresponse(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {         
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
    }
```

Comment: If you have access to the server logs, it might be worth looking through them to see if there are any errors being logged on that side.

Comment: I checked the server logs.Everything seems ok on the server side.

Comment: Ok so I tried running the server on localhost and everything is working fine.No volley errors. What could be the reason?